# What event should I handle to execute code when WinForms application switches from Run mode to Design mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am running a Windows form application and I need to execute a piece of code when I switch to design mode. I have a handler for the OnEnterDesignMode debugger event and this gets hit if I am debugging the application and then switch to design mode. However, this does not get hit if I initially start without debugging and then switch to design mode. What event do I need to handle in order that certain code is executed when switching from Run mode to Design mode?

Comment: How would the application switch from run mode to design mode?

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to release mode and debug mode?

If so you can wrap your code as follows:

```
#if DEBUG
            //Execute debug mode code
#else
            //execute release mode code
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the event, but there is a DesignMode bool property on a windows form, probably inherited from Control, that returns true if the form is open in the designer. Beware though, as DesignMode returns false in a constructor even when in design mode. So always use it in something like the load event, and not in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Try Component.DesignMode in your control. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.COMPONENTMODEL.COMPONENT.DESIGNMODE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV3.5%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

**VB.net Example**

```
 Private Sub txtSmartDate_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSmartDate.TextChanged
    If Not Me.DesignMode Then
        If _ValueInitialised And Not _SuppressEventCode Then
            '   Apply the changes to the property value, now the text box has been updated.
            Call SetPropertyValues()
            Call ApplyDateFormating()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```